# Variable undefined when set inside a function

Tags: javascript

```
 function setx(){
    var x = 'foobary bazer'
    showit();
 }

 function showit(){
   console.log(x);
 }

 setx();
```

In the above example, the `showit` function fails because x is undefined. However, x is set and is available in memory (or so I thought) before `showit` is called. Why is this not the case?

Also, what's the best way to make this code work, so the `console.log` does indeed print `foobary bazer` to the console? I could get rid of the `var` and make it a global, but I don't think this is the best way as it can cause strange bugs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Variable Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Comment: `var` creates a locally defined variable, which means that it is available in local scope only. In your case only inside `setx` function.

Comment: Just define `x` outside your function.

Comment: @putvande Making a variable global is a very wrong advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the `x` variable to the `showit` function:

```
function setx(){
    var x = 'foobary bazer'
    showit(x);
}

function showit(x){
    console.log(x);
}

setx();
```